# Salting a hash for authentication of plaintext (NOT a password)

Tags: hash, cryptography

I have a system that needs to send and receive data over an insecure channel. I want to keep this simple (it's running on an embedded platform, not a PC), and I don't mind if an attacker can read the data. What I want to prevent is an attacker intercepting the data and modifying it.

The platform has built-in functions for hashing (MD5, SHA1, etc), but not encryption, so what I thought I'd do is simply hash the data concatenated with some secret data to ensure that it was generated by my system and not an attacker. For example:

```
dataToSend = dataString + sha1(dataString + secretString)
```

The data string is sent in plaintext, followed by the hash. The secret part means that an attacker can't modify the data without invalidating the hash, unless they somehow discover the secret, which is built into the program and never sent over the channel. I'm aware that this scheme is susceptible to replay attacks; that's not a problem for this particular application.

My question is: if the secret is built into the app and never changes, is there a way someone could work out what it is, if they had a large collection of intercepted data strings and hashes? The executable the secret will be embedded in is itself encrypted by the platform, so there's no chance of discovering the secret with a hex editor.

Secondly, does it matter how long the secret is? The data string will typically be 8 bytes. If I have a much longer secret (e.g. 1024 bytes), to try to make it unguessable, then most of the input to the hash algorithm will never change. Does this make it less secure somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard technique for keyed authentication is [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac).  Unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise, I suggest you use HMAC for your problem.

Having the key longer than the data is a very good idea.  Your data is 64 bits, so using HMAC-SHA-256 would give a 256 bit key, twice as long as your data.  You could use a different key size if you wanted to, HMACs are pretty flexible about what size of key they accept.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! Thanks very much!